# Xamarin - The project is missing Android SDKs required for building

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, android-sdk-2.3

I downloaded a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. For installation, I selected only the Xamarin workload for mobile development. I created a new Xamarin.Forms project and it immediately gives the following error:

[image]

When I double click the message, I am prompted to Accept the Android SDK License Agreement. I click accept, and nothing changes, I just keep repeating those steps.

Navigating to the Android SDK Manager shows an empty list with an error:

[image]

All the solutions I have found online have not worked for me:

- Enable "Auto-Install Android SDKs" in Xamarin options
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Create custom AndroidSdkManager.exe.config file
- Uninstall and re-install Visual Studio
- Verified JAVA_HOME variable is set correctly

The only thing that resolved the error (before I uninstalled) was changing the Android SDK Manager repository from Microsoft to Google:

[image]

This doesn't seem like a proper solution given the warning message shown so I am wondering what else I can do.

Comment: Can you go to  Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings and then make sure that the "Auto Install Android SDKs" was checked?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes it is

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio 2019 and download it from [official website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, I downloaded and installed the latest version of Community 2019 from the official front page

Comment: Well, no idea what happened on your side, you can report a problem inside visual-studio to get more help:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on Windows 7. The issue was resolved after upgrading to Windows 10 and the Android SDKs installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue has not been resolved yet, try to:

1. Open Visual Studio as an admin because the software might be failing to read the files in your system.
2. Go to Visual Studio > Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager and go to the tools tab and install Android SDK Command Line tools.
3. Then now, you can double click on the error and the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running VS2022 17.4.2 and the same issue appeared on a new 7.0 Maui Blazor App.  Closing VS and Running as Administrator, reopening the project, then clicking on the error gave me a License Acceptance.  After accepting, all is well.